# Regenerating an attribute value on a timed cycle in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay, so my `User` models are able to 'spend' points to give `karma` (arbitrary points) to other users - each time the `User` gives a point, their `karma_amount` is decremented, as you might expect. I'd been originally planning on making it so a user couldn't give `karma` to another user more than once, but then I thought that it would be cooler to have a finite stock of points that replenishes, by say 1 point every two days.

I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this though - if it was a Ruby script on my machine, sure, but does anybody have any tips having tried something similar in Rails?

My other concern is that if every user has a ticking clock on the live app that'll slow the whole thing down. I guess what I'm asking in a nutshell is: what is the 'Rails-y' way of doing this? Naturally I'd rather find something robust or elegant than just hacking away.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You want something that run every period of time (two hours in your example). The operation itself (replenish_karma) could be a simple controller action (be sure to restrict its access, still), then you just need to be sure to call it on a regular basis.

A very simple way could be a simple [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on the server that would initiate a call to that specific route. If you want something inside your rails application, you may want to take a look at background task libs such as [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check these out. As the app isn't on a dedicated server I'm not sure it'll be a cron job, but will look into that as well!

Comment: The cron is the "easy way". Resque and delayed_job are very nice libraries, but require some work to make them function properly (they can do a lot more than just scheduling call, of course). If your functionality can be exposer as a route, you could theoretically call if from anywhere where the application can be accessed. Again, take care of the security issues (this is clearly an "administrator" functionality).